# How can I eliminate excess memory in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a complicated bit of code in which I am essentially adding a lot of sorted numpy arrays to a set (using a hashable ndarray class I wrote, see below) in a process pool. I used a hashable numpy array to save memory (much smaller than using tuple). But despite this optimization, this program still runs out of memory.

I managed to simplify the complicated code I am actually running to a minimal example:

```
import gc
import os
import numpy as np
import psutil
from pympler import asizeof

class hashable_ndarray:

    __slots__ = '__arr'

    def __init__(self, arr: np.ndarray):
        self.__arr = arr.copy()

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.__arr.data.tobytes())

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.__arr[key]

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return np.array_equal(self.__arr,  other.__arr)

    def copy(self):
        return self.__arr.copy()

def get_obj_size(obj):
    return asizeof.asizeof(obj) / 1024 ** 2

def get_total_mem():
    return psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2

def pack(arr) -> object:
    packed_reactions = hashable_ndarray(np.array(sorted(arr)))
    return packed_reactions

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_set = set()
    for i in range(1000000):
        my_set.add(pack(np.random.randint(0, 1000, 20).astype(np.int16)))
    gc.collect()
    print(f'total mem: {get_total_mem()}')
    print(f'set mem: {get_obj_size(my_set)}')
    print(f'set len: {len(my_set)}')
    print(f'estimated size np arrays {get_obj_size(np.random.randint(0, 1000, 20).astype(np.int16))*len(my_set)}')
```

This outputs:

```
total mem: 565.890625
set mem: 77.77658081054688
set len: 1000000
estimated size np arrays 144.95849609375
```

(values are in megabytes). Note that I am calling gc.collect() before printing memory stats so the problem cannot be garbage collection. Also note that the size of the set and numpy arrays do not add up to the total memory.

The ratio of total memory to memory used by the set and numpy array size estimate ("estimated size np arrays") appears to be roughly the same regardless of the amount of items I put in the set. So it doesn't seem like this extra memory could be due to some kind of process overhead. Something is actually growing proportionally with the set.

Is this just due to inaccurate estimation of object sizes? I noticed that asizeof ignores the numpy objects within hashable_ndarray (hence including the estimate). Is there something else it is ignoring? If not, does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Expression '(np.array(sorted(arr))' might be a problem. What if arr was sorted in place?